# running spring cloud stream application as web app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring cloud stream application which I also want to run as a web app. The reason I need to hit at http://host:8080/ to see if the application is up to health check. I have following dependencies but it would spin up tomcat and error I get is unable to establish connection on port 8080

```
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit'

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.23'
```

is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot and Cloud are you using? I just created a demo app using https://start.spring.io with those dependencies, Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Greenwich.SR2 and I can start the app and go to http://localhost:8080/ without any problem.

Did you try to go to http://localhost:8080/ instead of http://host:8080/ (which you mentioned in your post)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the [ref. guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control), as far as you've included `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependencies in the classpath, you should be able to access the Actuator endpoints.

You can double-check whether or not they are in the classpath with variations to the following command:

> jar tvf YOUR-APP.jar | grep actuator

Also, starting with Boot 2.0, the exposition of actuator endpoints are disabled by default.

So, depending on the version in use, you may have to also start the application with `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` key/value pair, so they are enabled, and that you can access them via HTTP.